# how to install latest version of nodejs in Ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, nodejs

I have tried so many solutions to install the latest version of nodes js in my system but it did not work any .Its only installing node version `v5.12.0`  which is not supporting `vuejs`.

out put of `type -a node nodejs` is

```
node is /usr/local/bin/node
node is /usr/bin/node
nodejs is /usr/bin/nodejs
```

And the output of `apt-cache policy nodejs` is

```
nodejs:
  Installed: 5.12.0-1nodesource1~xenial1
  Candidate: 5.12.0-1nodesource1~xenial1
  Version table:
 *** 5.12.0-1nodesource1~xenial1 500
        500 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_5.x xenial/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     4.2.6~dfsg-1ubuntu4.1 500
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 Packages
     4.2.6~dfsg-1ubuntu4 500
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: I just followed the link still its downloaded the `5.12.0` version for me . Any suggestions ?

Comment: Remove version 5.12.0 and then run `sudo apt-get install curl  && curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | sudo -E bash - && sudo apt-get install -y nodejs`

Comment: @karel : i have done the same way still the version is older one . :(

Comment: `sudo apt-get remove nodejs npm` removes  the existing version of nodejs in Ubuntu.

Comment: I have done the same when i run this command `curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | sudo -E bash -` it says `## Installing the NodeSource Node.js v8.x repo...` after running this command `sudo apt-get install -y nodejs` it says  `Unpacking nodejs (5.12.0-1nodesource1~xenial1) ...` . I dont understand why its getting the older version .

Comment: Add the output of `type -a node nodejs` and `apt-cache policy nodejs` to the question, please.

Comment: @muru : i have added the outputs to my question Please check

Answer (score 4):

You can try using Node Version Manager (NVM). You can find it on github [here](https://github.com/creationix/nvm).

Briefly information to install `nvm` and `node` (see github repository for more information):

- Install `nvm`:

  ```
  wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.2/install.sh | bash
  ```
- Update Ubuntu environment variables. This commands let you run `nvm` from any place inside your terminal:

  ```
  export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"

  [ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"
  ```
- Check nvm is installed:

  ```
  nvm --version
  ```
- Install latest version of `node` (version selected by default):

  ```
  nvm install node
  ```
- Check `node` version:

  ```
  node -v
  ```

---

**Note**: if you aren't be able to open node the first time, try to close and reopen your shell.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the Previous one using:

```
sudo apt-get remove nodejs npm
```

Re install using PPA(Current Release):

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | sudo -E bash -
```

For LTS:

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | sudo -E bash -
```

Comment: When i run the second command it says `## Installing the NodeSource Node.js v8.x repo...` but version is 5.12.0 :(

Comment: try to remove the previous one , install a fresh one using above!

Comment: Its the same case its not updating to the latest version i dont understand why ?

Answer (score 1):

Facing the same issue not able to update from 5.12.0 to 6.x LTS version.But resolved it by following the instructions as mentioned in Nodejs.org

No need to remove the older version and all.

For upgrading to 6.x version:
Run the below commands:

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

For upgrading to 8.x version:
Run the below commands:

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

Answer (score 0):

```
apt-cache madison nodejs

echo "deb https://deb.nodesource.com/node_8.x xenial main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource_8.x.list
curl --silent https://deb.nodesource.com/gpgkey/nodesource.gpg.key | apt-key add -

apt-get --assume-yes update
apt-get --assume-yes upgrade

apt-cache madison nodejs

apt-get --assume-yes install nodejs
```

Answer (score 0):

Install it from the official site,

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

You are able to install other versions by simply changing the `setup_12.x`, `12` is the version.

[Offical Link](https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x)

Answer (score 0):

All stable releases are available as snap packages.

https://snapcraft.io/node

Command-line install:

```
sudo snap install node --channel=12/stable --classic
```

Verify versions:

```
node -v
npm -v
```

https://nodesource.com/blog/installing-nodejs-tutorial-using-snaps-on-linux

Answer (score 0):

I would leave the version installed by your distro alone.

If you need a specific version for a development project, download the exact version you need from `https://nodejs.org/en/` and un-tar the file (typically under /opt) and run it from there.

e.g.

```
cd /opt
wget https://nodejs.org/dist/v13.6.0/node-v13.6.0-linux-x64.tar.xz
tar xvf node-v13.6.0-linux-x64.tar.xz

node-v13.6.0-linux-x64/bin/node

Welcome to Node.js v13.6.0.
Type ".help" for more information.
>
```

Good security practice to verify the shasums `https://nodejs.org/dist/v13.6.0/SHASUMS256.txt.asc`

If you do this, avoid using `npm -g` with the version not supported by you distro.

This approach ensures that any code that uses node in the rest of your system will not be caught out by finding an unsupported version. Technically this is needed if the major semver version is different from that provided by your distro, in reality running the future nodejs major versions is safe with most code.